# Convert Formula Value to Static Value if Cell is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using a script that calculates the miles between locations. For example in Column A San Diego, CA in Column B San Francisco in Column C 508.3. If Column A or Column B is === "" then it sets the column to "".

```
// Note: This is not my code. 

function DrivingMeters(origin, destination) {
    var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .getDirections();
    return directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
}

function DrivingMiles(origin, destination) {
  if (origin === "" || destination === "") {
    return "";
  } else {
  return DrivingMeters(origin, destination)/1609.34;
  }
}
```

I am trying to limit the number of API calls I make because I have a lot of information which is added regularly. The first step I took is returning "" before the API call if either column is blank. What I would also like to do is convert cells in Column C that are !== "" to a static value removing the formula all together. Thanks in advance!

Comment: About ``What I would also like to do is convert cells in Column C that are !== "" to a static value removing the formula all together.``, when do you want to do this? For example, with using the OnEdit event trigger, when the custom function is put in a cell of the column "C" and when the column "C" is empty? Or without using the trigger, do you want to convert all formulas of the column "C", which has the empty result, to the static values in the Spreadsheet by manually running a script?

Comment: @Tanaike I think it would be nice if this could be accomplished at the time the function runs, so in the function itself. Maybe it could return a static value. On edit would be great too. I'd even be okay if I had to manually run it on occasion.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed 2 sample scripts for achieving your goal as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Please select one of them. If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I only want cells that have been returned with a value eg C1 508.3 mi to be converted to a static value. Cells that haven't returned a value should keep the formula. eg A2 San Diego B2 "" C2 (has formula). I apologize I may have explained that poorly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. And please don't apologize. The reason that my answer was not the suitable for your situation is due to my poor English skill. So I would like to confirm for correctly understand your goal. You want to convert the formula to the value of the column "C", when the column "C" has the value. On the other hand, when the column "C" has no values, you want to keep the formulas. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your goal. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? Please select one of 2 samples for your situation. If those were not the results you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As a test case, you put a custom formula to the column "C1" like `=DrivingMiles(A1,B1)`.
- When the value of the column "C" is NOT empty, you want to convert the formulas to the static value.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

From your reply comment, I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, when the custom formula of `=DrivingMiles()` is put, when the returned value is NOT empty, the formula is converted to the value.

For this situation, I used the OnEdit event trigger of the simple trigger. When you use this script, please copy and paste the following script, and put the custom formula like `=DrivingMiles(A1,B1)`. When the returned value is NOT empty, the formula is automatically converted to the static value.

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var value = e.range.getValue();
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 3 && ~e.range.getFormula().toUpperCase().indexOf("=DRIVINGMILES(") && value) {
    e.range.setValue(value);
  }
}
```

- If you want to run the OnEdit event trigger for the specific sheet, please modify above script.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, when the following script is run, the cells of the column "C" are converted from the formulas to the values when the cell has the value and the formula or only value.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1); // Column "C"
  var values = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var convertedValues = values.map(function(e, i) {return e[0] && formulas[i][0] || e[0] ? [e[0]] : [formulas[i][0]]});
  range.setValues(convertedValues);
}
```

- This can be used for the active sheet.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Tanaike - these are works of art, as always. For the benefit of we learners, would you please explain the functioning of the `if` statement in Pattern1 and the last two lines of code in Pattern2.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for your comment. 1. About ``the if statement in Pattern1``, when the column "C" is edit and the put formula includes ``=DRIVINGMILES(`` and the value is ``""``, it becomes true. 2. About ``the last two lines of code in Pattern2``, when the condition, that the value is ``""`` and the formula is put, is true and false, the a1Notation and ``""`` is returned, respectively. Then, the ranges of a1Notations are cleared. Now I updated my answer. So when you check the original script, please check [the revision of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56677145/revisions).

Comment: @Tedinoz As an additional explanation, ``~`` of ``~e.range.getFormula().toUpperCase().indexOf("=DRIVINGMILES(")`` is the bitwise inversion operator. I used this for judging true or false. For example, ``~"abc".indexOf("b")`` and ``~"abc".indexOf("d")`` are ``-2`` and ``0``, respectively. When these are used for the if statement, those work true and false, respectively.

Comment: @Tanaike It works, wonderfully. Thank you! If you have a PayPal I would love to buy you a coffee.

Comment: @Brandon Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tedinoz Welcome. Thank you for replying. If it will be useful for you, I'm glad.