# How do I get a cell to retain text, after the cell it pulls from changes text?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, finance, quantitative-finance

This question will have two parts. If you're willing to help me out, feel free to address whichever chunk you've got the time or interest for. Thanks in advance.

Assume there are two cells in a spreadsheet, the first (A1) has the text `hello` inside, and the second (A2) has `=T(A1)`, so they now both say hello. If I want to change the text in A1, but want the text in A2 to continue to read `hello`, is there a way to automate this?

For some context, this is part of a larger project where I want to create a column of stock tickers that I like. Ideally, I could type the ticker name into a cell, check a box if I want to track it, and it would automatically add itself to a column. Where the first part of this question becomes relevant is that I would then move on to another stock, deleting the first ticker I wrote, but still wanting it in my column.

The second part of the question is about making the column. My instinct would be to use the `=ARRAYFORMULA` function, but that draws from a column to begin with, so I'm a little bit stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, in your situation, when you don't want to change the value of `=T(A1)` in the cell "A2", how about converting the function to the value using the OnEdit trigger? By this, when `=T(A1)` is put to the cell, the result value of the formula can be fixed as the value instead of the formula. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56676805) might be the related question. But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

### answer for Q1:

no, not possible unless you hardcode A2 as:

```
=T("hello")
```

or you use a script to remember your value but in that case, the A2 will host a custom function instead of the formula you mentioned

ofc what you are mentioning with those tickers, checkboxes and moving values around it's completely doable with a script

---

### answer for Q2:

it depends on the formulae you use. not all formulas are supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`